# Subir imágenes a una carpeta de mi proyecto JAVA / JSP / SERVLETS

Tags: java, jsp

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, estoy realizando una aplicación Web, de una pizzería, estoy intentando crear un Dashboard (o centro de administración), donde puedan agregar nuevos productos / novedades, tengo un formulario que capta todos los datos necesarios y una imagen, y así mismo tengo mi servlet recibiendo estos datos y procesando la imagen (La guardo en la Base de Datos a través del nombre del archivo), quisiera que la imagen que subieran quedará en una carpeta especifica ("proyecto"/"web"/"img"), pero al hacerlo con el código que tengo me la guarda en ("proyecto"/"build"/"web"/"img"), y me está dando problemas al hacer un **CLEAN AND BUILD**, ya que me borra todo lo que se encuentre en esa ruta, y las imágenes no quedan. Adjunto código

Código del formulario:

```html
<form action="CrearProducto.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="text">Nombre de Producto</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="text">Descripcion</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Ingrese Descripcion" rows="4" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="text">Precio</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="pre" placeholder="Ingrese Precio" required>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="text">Tipo de producto</label>
                                            <select class="form-control input-lg" required name="tipo" >
                                                <option style="display:none;" value="">Seleccione el producto</option>
                                                <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
                                                <option value="lasana">Lasa&ntilde;a</option>
                                                <option value="pasta">Pasta</option>
                                                <option value="panzerotti">Panzerotti</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="fileupload">Imagen</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="img">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Crear</button>
                                    </form>
```

Adjunto código de mi servlet

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String desc = request.getParameter("desc");
    String tipo = request.getParameter("tipo");
    int precio = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("pre"));
    //Procesamiento de foto 
    Part archivo = request.getPart("img");
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    System.out.println(path);
    String fotoName = "";
    Negocio n = new Negocio();
    if (archivo.getSize() > 0) {
        String foto = Paths.get(archivo.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
        String[] f = foto.split("\\.");
        int count = n.getCountPro();
        int idMax=(count>0)?n.getLastPro():0;   
        fotoName = tipo + idMax + "." + f[1];
        archivo.write(path + File.separator + fotoName);
    }
    
    String alert = n.crearProducto(0, name, desc, precio, tipo, fotoName);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("alert", alert);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("crearProducto.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

De igual forma también he leído que podría ser recomendable guardar los archivos en un WebApp o en un servidor distinto, para limitar los recursos, había pensado en GoogleDrive con su api, pero nunca la he usado y no hay mucha documentación para Java con Netbeans.

Comment: Eso te sucede porque aún estás en fase de desarrollo y ejecutas la aplicacion desde un área de desarrollo. La carpeta Proyecto/build/ supuestamente. Es para el IDE y debe contener la estructura de tu aplicación web pero no debería ser la real. Claro si haces Clean and Build lógico que te borre todo porque aún estás en ambiente de pruebas. En producción si deberías tener la carpeta que quieras y nadie la borra porque no necesario más Build. Al menos es lo que percibo.

Comment: Ahora también podrías ponerlo en directorio fuera de todo: /imágenes o C:\imagenes son directorios que están fuera de la estructura de directorios del web. Lógicamente para mostrarlos tienes que leerlos y enviarlos como stream ya que no podrías tener una url directa hacia ellos.

Comment: Hey Juan, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me quitaste de dudas, quisiera preguntar también si has usado la api de Google drive, me gustaría en un futuro almacenar allí, quedó atento

Comment: No, no he usado esas apis.